# Rails: how can I test a stopwatch in my Capybara integration tests?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, capybara, integration-testing, testunit

Currently writing tests for my Rails app's time tracking functionality. I can't figure out a way to simulate clicking the "play" button on the timer, waiting a few seconds, clicking pause and then submitting the form (creating a new Timestamp object).

```
test "track time with stopwatch" do
    visit new_project_timestamp_path(@project)
    find('#play_button').click 
    sleep 4.0
    find('#pause_button').click
    click_button "submit_new_timestamp"
    visit project_path(@project)
    assert page.has_content? "4 seconds"
 end
```

^This is the gist of what I want it to do, but sleep obviously doesn't work because it suspends the thread completely, whereas I want the test to kind of "wait around" while the stopwatch does its thing for a few seconds. The above test fails because no time is actually tracked; pause is clicked immediately after play, in the eyes of the timer, and so the form is submitted with no actual time logged, which of course throws a validation error.

Is there a way I'd be able to simulate waiting a few seconds without actually suspending the thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Note: huge thanks to Tom Walpole for his answer. The issue was that I wasn't using a JS-enabled web driver. Thought I'd write this for anyone else having similar problems due to the same lack of understanding I had.)

The issue is that I wasn't using a web driver that executes Javascript. By default Capybara uses the `:rack_test` driver which, while fast, doesn't execute Javascript.

So for integration tests that rely on JS being executed (in my case interacting with a stopwatch), something like `:poltergeist` is a good idea. To set it up, add

```
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'phantomjs', :require => 'phantomjs/poltergeist'
```

to the Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

You'll need to add

```
  require 'capybara/poltergeist'
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
```

to your test/spec helper file. Then all you need to do is set `Capybara.current_driver = Capybara.javascript_driver` wherever you need a JS-enabled integration test.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a JS capable driver (selenium, poltergeist, capybara-webkit) then the browser, app under test, and tests all run in their own threads/processes, so sleeping in your test thread should be perfectly fine.  Rather than it submitting both clicks with no difference in time it's more likely that your `click_button` is being cancelled by the `visit` immediately following it, and therefore you're not getting a new timestamp created.  You need to assert for some kind of visible change between the 'click_button` and 'visit' to ensure the creating a new timestamp action has completed before telling the browser to request a new page

```
click_button "submit_new_timestamp"
page.assert_text "Timestamp created" # whatever message/visible change occurs after clicking the button
visit project_path(@project)
```

Additionally, using the assert_text, assert_selector, assert_title, assert_current_path matchers will provide you with better error messages, when assertions fail, than asserting on the `has_xxx?` methods

Comment: The error messages the form (and the test logs) show that the seconds_elapsed field in the form doesn't get filled in. 

This is filled with the number of seconds tracked by the stopwatch upon submit using jQuery, so my guess would be it isn't being executed properly or at all (this works fine in development and in production).

I'll try to switch up the drivers, maybe that will solve it. If not, maybe there's a bug somewhere in the jQuery code that's only showing up in the test environment.

Comment: @BenLawton How are you filling in the form fields, JS click handler?  If so are you using a JS capable driver (the default capybara rack-test driver doesn't execute JS)?

Comment: Was originally using the default, but I just tried setting `Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium` to no effect.

Comment: @BenLawton - setting javascript_driver won't do anything if you don't  change current_driver to it for the test.  To test try putting `Capybara.current_driver = :selenium` as the first line of your test, then afterwards go and read https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#using-capybara-with-testunit  and get your test environment set up correctly

Comment: Wonderful, that did the job. Thanks! :)

Comment: @BenLawton Glad it helped - don't forget to accept the answer, if it helped, so the question is marked as answered

Comment: It was your comments, rather than the answer, that solved the problem for me. I've written them up in my own answer, for people who might be having the same issues due to the same lack of understanding in the future. Thanks!